# How to handle slash command post requests from slack in C#

Tags: c#, rest, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am currently trying to setup a slack bot in C# using azure. I am new to interacting with http requests in C#, and am having trouble getting the post request from slack to work. When I call my slash commands in slack, I am met with an http_client_error and no other error information. Does anyone have any resources they could point me towards about working with slack commands in c#. Any recent help would be much appreciated. I cannot program the bot in another language due to limitations of a dll I am using. I guess the main question I have is how to handle http post requests from slack in C#.

Answer (score 0):

When you give slack the link that it needs to send the HTTP Post to, make sure you have https:// at the start of the link.